# DLL compatibility for different compilers

Tags: c++, dll

Try to don't judge me really hard for this question.

Will I have problems if I try to use a DLL (written in C++) in a Visual Studio project that was compiled with the MinGW toolchain (g++)?

If the answer is yes, could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as code execution goes, if it targets Windows, then it should run.

For interoperability; it depends on the API exposed from the dll.

- If it is a "C" style API then you should be fine.
- If it is a C++ API with classes and STL use, then you may run into trouble using different compilers (even different settings in the compilers). C++ doesn't have a standard ABI.

---

As noted in the comments and probably worth touching on here; the "C" style API is more than just the function calls, compatibility includes (but not limited) to things such as;

- Memory allocation; general rule is "deallocation must be done by the same code as the allocation" - i.e. in the dll such that the matching allocation/deallocation is used (e.g. `new` and `delete`, `malloc` and `free`, `CustomAlloc` and `CustomDealloc`)
- Data alignment and packing, not all compilers have the same defaults
- Calling conventions, again, not all compilers have the same defaults, when in doubt, be explicit on what that convention should be (e.g. `__stdcall`)

As for the C++ ABI, in addition to all of the above, incompatibilities include;

- Name mangling
- STL class and container implementations
- Separate and different implementations of `new` and `delete`, with custom memory pooling etc.
- Exception mechanisms, e.g. generation, and stack unwinding

These are not comprehensive lists, but they go some way to motivating the general advice that *when possible, use the same toolchains and same compiler/linker settings*.

Comment: For example, `std::string` and `std::set<long>` or `std::cout` are likely to have different and incompatible implementations between MinGW & Visual Studio. And name mangling might be different. And also exception handling.

Comment: TBH it would be quite weird to have an **interface** mention `std::cout`. It's perfectly OK to use `std::cout` **inside** the DLL. However, don't expect `std::cout << std::hex` from the MinGW side to affect the `std::cout`  object on the VC++ side. OTOH, if you return a `int*` allocated by `new`, it may appear to be a C interface from the type, but the requirement to call `delete ptr` still makes it a C++ interface.

Comment: You should note that binaries compiled for different native architectures are not compatible (i.e. a DLL built for x86 and a DLL built for x64 won't work together).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about DLL. It's about how you describe such DLL to your compiler (ie. header files and exports).

Those descriptions affect how your code expect on data layout (e.g. different compiler may have different default alignment and padding), or even different code path (e.g. resolve to different inline functions and macro, such as in STL case).

Then each compiler may have different name mangling scheme, you may need a bit hack to glue the codes.

With very special care on the above issues you should be fine using a DLL from different compiler.

Answer (score -3):

No, because it is all one standard. And in fact your C++ application compiled with gcc calls system functions from OS dll files. So no matter if you call them manually or automatically, it is all the same.

Comment: Wrong. The ABI is perhaps different. The standard C++ library internals (e.g. implementation details and structure layout for `std::map` or `std::string`) is different. The standard defines the behavior of an implementation from the C++ source code. It does not know about compilers.

Comment: For all downvoters and previous comment. There's not difference in compiled code as it is machine code + system calls, structure is a little different - that's the fact, but not for just plain functions.But as long as you code in C style there is no difference. Your program needs windows libraries to start at all and it makes calls to those dlls. So to sum up - you have to make some thigns with care

Comment: But you cannot reliably link a `.obj` object file compiled with MinGW to a library (including the standard C++ one) compiled with VisualStudio or vice versa. You'll even have compatibilities issues between a GCC 4.9 based MinGW and a GCC 5 based MinGW! In practice, a C++ header contains a lot of internal `struct`-s or `class`es and `inline`-d functions (or methods) and these are different..... And exception handling is different too.....

Comment: Who talks about object files (that are actually .o files in gcc). At this step it is very different and totally different linker is used. Also there are at least few standards for object files (at least in linux, not sure about VC), so this topic seams to be clear.

Comment: On Linux, you can even have compatibility issues between GCC 4.9 & GCC 5, or between code compiled by Clang 3.5 and GCC 5.0